# css3 gradient with line on top

Tags: html, css

so im trying to make an infographic to a website im making and i want to make a gradient that has a line on top like in this image: https://ibb.co/e8xmCk where there is a gradient and a line on top of it with a diffrent color and that to be a background of a specific place. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I was really unable to understand your question actually, but 
nevertheless I have made a solution that you want like..

```css
.container {width: 100%; height: 200px; background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; z-index: 1;}
.container:before {display: block; content: ""; height: 10%; width: 100%; background: red; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: -1;}
h1 {font-family: Arial; font-size: 49px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; text-align: center; margin: 0px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <h1>This is text here..!</h1>
</div>
```

And another is here...

```css
.container {width: 100%; height: 200px; background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; z-index: 1; overflow-y: hidden;}
.container:before {display: block; content: ""; height: 10%; width: 100%; background: red; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: -1;}
.side-panel {height: 100%; width: 30%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -10%; background: #2493a4; z-index: -2; transform: skew(20deg);}
h1 {font-family: Arial; font-size: 49px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; text-align: center; margin: 0px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="side-panel"></div>
 <h1>This is text here..!</h1>
</div>
```